# Como fazer um teste falhar se demorar demais?

Tags: c#, testes-de-unidade, mstest

Eu estou usando MSTest que é a plataforma default de testes de unidade no visual studio e tenho este teste aqui:

```
    [TestMethod]
    [ExpectedException(typeof(InvalidOperationException))]
    public void Board_nao_destroi_unidades_flutuantes()
    {
        var ctor = new Construction();
        Board.Unities.Add(ctor);
        Board.DestroyAllUnities();
    }
```

Ele está esperando uma exception para passar mas ao invés disto ele **entra em loop** e atrasa os outros 92 testes.
Qual é a maneira de dizer que se meu teste **demorar** uma certa quantidade de milisegundos ele irá falhar?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Conforme diz o site da MSDN (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms243175.aspx) basta usar o atributo Timeout.

```
[TestMethod(), Timeout(80)]
public void MyTestMethod()
```

Comment: Resolveu obrg. Eu sabia que existiam só não sabia como procurar.